# Whats similar and different in Creating Threads in Java and .NET?

Tags: java, .net, multithreading

In Java we can create a thread and pass a runnabe object ,

```
  new Thread( new Runnable() {
//Functions to happen
        public void run() {
 Textbox2.text="Selected";
}
}
).start();
```

whats the way in .NET to have this functionality.?

Comment: Did you try to google it? http://bit.ly/164miRQ

Comment: About 1,590,000 results (0.14 seconds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the time you shouldn't have to create your own thread. But if you want something almost identical, use

```
new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => {
    // do something
})).Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

practice this example

```
namespace Programming_CSharp
{
  using System;
  using System.Threading;
  class Tester
  {
    static void Main( )
    {
      // make an instance of this class
      Tester t = new Tester( );
      // run outside static Main
      t.DoTest( );
    }
    public void DoTest( )
    {
      // create a thread for the Incrementer
      // pass in a ThreadStart delegate
      // with the address of Incrementer
      Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Incrementer) );
      // create a thread for the Decrementer
      // pass in a ThreadStart delegate
      // with the address of Decrementer
      Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Decrementer) );
      // start the threads
      t1.Start( );
      t2.Start( );
    }
    // demo function, counts up to 1K
    public void Incrementer( )
    {
      for (int i =0;i<1000;i++)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Incrementer: {0}", i);
      }
    }
    // demo function, counts down from 1k
    public void Decrementer( )
    {
      for (int i = 1000;i>=0;i--)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Decrementer: {0}", i);
      }
    }
  }
}
```